# t-sql pivot - monthly revenue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm having trouble figuring out how to construct the `PIVOT` for my revenue query.

First, here's my query:

```
SELECT  DATENAME(month,
             CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, TransactionMonth) + '/1'
             + '/2013')) AS MONTH ,
    RevenueGroup ,
    AMOUNT
FROM    ( SELECT    f.TransactionMonth ,
                f.RevenueGroupID ,
                '$'
                + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(SUM(f.LineItemAmount) AS MONEY), -1) AS Revenue ,
                MIN(f.RevenueGroup) AS RevenueGroup
      FROM      Financials(@StartDate, @EndDate, @SiteID) f
      GROUP BY  f.TransactionMonth ,
                f.RevenueGroupID
    ) AS Rev
ORDER BY Rev.TransactionMonth DESC ,
        CAST(Revenue AS MONEY) DESC
```

And here is my result set:

```
MONTH       RevenueGroup         AMOUNT
December    Dues - Collect       $425,725.71
December    NMS                  $78,444.17
December    Personal Training    $58,511.53
November    Dues - Collect       $425,683.75
November    NMS                  $114,710.25
November    Personal Training    $66,277.49
October     Dues - Collect       $419,250.09
October     NMS                  $96,098.86
October     Personal Training    $58,725.77
```

And here is how the result set needs to look after the sql PIVOT:

```
RevenueGroup        DECEMBER      NOVEMBER      OCTOBER
Dues - Collect      $425,725.71   $425,683.75   $419,250.09
NMS                 $78,444.17    $114,710.25   $96,098.86
Personal Training   $58,511.53    $66,277.49    $58,725.77
```

How can I achieve this with T-SQL PIVOT?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable ([MONTH] NVARCHAR(20),RevenueGroup NVARCHAR(100),AMOUNT NUMERIC(20,2))
GO
INSERT INTO #MyTable
VALUES
('December','Dues - Collect',       425725.71),
('December','NMS',                  78444.17),
('December','Personal Training',    58511.53),
('November','Dues - Collect',       425683.75),
('November','NMS',                  114710.25),
('November','Personal Training',    66277.49),
('October','Dues - Collect',       419250.09),
('October','NMS',                  96098.86),
('October','Personal Training',    58725.77)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT RevenueGroup, [October],[November],[December]
FROM (SELECT * FROM #MyTable)t   --<-- Your Existing Query can go in here but do not
  PIVOT                             -- not do any formating like Dollar sign as you want
      (                             -- sum the results by month later on    
      SUM(AMOUNT)
      FOR [MONTH]
      IN ([October],[November],[December])
      )P
```

**Result**

```
╔═══════════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║   RevenueGroup    ║  October  ║ November  ║ December  ║
╠═══════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ Dues - Collect    ║ 419250.09 ║ 425683.75 ║ 425725.71 ║
║ NMS               ║ 96098.86  ║ 114710.25 ║ 78444.17  ║
║ Personal Training ║ 58725.77  ║ 66277.49  ║ 58511.53  ║
╚═══════════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: M.Ali, you're awesome! Works great. One more thing would put icing on this cake. The months have to be dynamic. For example, since this is December 2013, my month columns have to be December, November, October (past 3 months). In a few days it will be January and then I'll need the months January, December, November. My original query handles dynamic months no problem, but with the pivot I'm not sure how.

Comment: If I should create a new question, just let me know.

Comment: @SweatCoder dont worry about a new question just in your inner query add a `WHERE` clause something like `MONTH(ColumnName) >= MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()))`

Comment: @SweatCoder for dynamic month you will need to build the IN clause in you pivot table using dynamic sql

Comment: @M.Ali ... Just a small nit-pick detail. I think you want it to be -2 in your DATEADD as -3 will get you three months back and will result in a total of four months reported.

Answer (score 1):

This already has a best answer and this is not meant to be an answer, but an addendum hint on how to capture the dynamic months for the dynamic SQL...

```
Declare @dynamicColumns Nvarchar(64)

Select  @dynamicColumns = Coalesce(@dynamicColumns + ',','') + '[' + m.months + ']'
From   (Select  0 As monthSubtract
        Union
        Select  1
        Union
        Select  2) As ms
Cross   Apply (Select DateName(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH, -ms.monthSubtract, GETDATE())) As months) m
Order   By ms.monthSubtract Desc

Select  @dynamicColumns
```